# what javascript arrays/objects type to use?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, web

In my ASP.NET page, I want to return some data from the client-side form, which is preferable to be stored as a dictionary object.  Now, I'm not very sure what type of object to use in my JavaScript function, which once accessed from the code-behind on the server (through Request.Cookies/**any other suggested alternate way**), can then be used as a .NET dictionary object?

Currently I'm saving the data as a specifically formatted string and then, on the server, I'm splitting it into arrays to use it.  So, I'm just eager to know  a better and of course, neater way to do this?

Comment: have you considered using JSON format? ,writing directly over the page as string and parsing it

Comment: yes I tried, but didn't know how to convert it into a .net dictionary object, and that's where I got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json to transfer the data - it works great in Javascript and is supported in .Net 4.0.

First store the data in a javascript object and stringify it:

```
var data = {}
data.name = "Joe";
data.age = 17;

// ... whatever else you do ...

// convert to string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

// ... put in cookie, or use ajax, or use something else to give it to .Net
```

Then on the .Net side, you can use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` to convert the json to a Dictionary:

```
String jsonString = HoweverYouGetIt();
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string,object> data = serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString) as Dictionary<string,object>;
//you can now use (int)data["name"]
```

`JavaScriptSerializer` can be found in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly which is only in .NET 4.0, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net.) has other alternatives.

As for how to transmit the data - if it's a dynamic web app, use ajax.  If it's a website that collects data throughout multiple pages, use cookies.

And as always, be sure to sanitize any inputs!

Comment: thanks @MackieChan, **System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject()** was what I was looking for.